# A tricky question about the unimodal and antimodal functions

Tags: functions, asymptotics

We have two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ that are completely unrelated to each other. One of them is unimodal (a), and the other is anti-modal (b), i.e. having one maximum and one minimum, respectively. We only know the type of modality, but we do not know anything about their structure and position of it's maximum or minimum!

[image]

**Problem:** I was wondering if it is possible to convert one to another, but with some conditions:

1. When converting unimodal $f(x)$ to antimodal $g(x)$, it is necessary to make the minimum of the obtained antimodal function $g(x)$ equal to $0$, or asymptotically approach it, i.e. $min_g(x) → 0$.
2. When converting antimodal $g(x)$ to unimodal $f(x)$, it is necessary to make the maximum of the obtained unimodal function $f(x)$ equal to $1$, or asymptotically approach it, i.e. $max_f(x) → 1$.

Under some assumptions, this can be done as follows: the unimodal f(x) "pass" through the *logarithm*, and the anti-modal $g(x)$ through the *Gauss function*.

But I don't know how to fulfill the two conditions above.

I would be grateful for any advice and help!

Comment: Maybe call them different things? Say f(x) and g(x)?

Comment: @Countable

I edit question.

Comment: What is the relation between your question and `constructive-mathematics`?